# How do I bind a ComboBox to a list that is inside of an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, observablecollection

So I have an ObservableCollection of type AcquisitionDeviceInfo, which is a custom class, this custom class has a property of type `List<string>` I want to display the contents of this list inside a combobox and i want to be able to capture the selected item, but I don't know how to do it properly.

I have tried to bind the combobox to my observable collection and to set the DisplayMemberPath property to my list but it doesn't work.

**EDIT 1:** I've changed my code to a MVCE so it's easier for you guys to see what i'm trying to do.

Here is my AcquisitionDeviceInfo class.

```cs
public class AcquisitionDeviceInfo
    {
        private List<string> _device;

        public AcquisitionDeviceInfo()
        {
            _device = new List<string>();
        }

        public List<string> Device { get => _device; set => _device = value; }
    }
```

This is my code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<AcquisitionDeviceInfo> _observableAcquisitionDevices;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            _observableAcquisitionDevices = new ObservableCollection<AcquisitionDeviceInfo>();

            AcquisitionDeviceInfo Info1 = new AcquisitionDeviceInfo { Device = { "A", "B", "C" } };
            AcquisitionDeviceInfo Info2 = new AcquisitionDeviceInfo { Device = { "D", "E", "F" } };
            AcquisitionDeviceInfo Info3 = new AcquisitionDeviceInfo { Device = { "G", "H", "I" } };

            ObservableAcquisitionDevices.Add(Info1);
            ObservableAcquisitionDevices.Add(Info2);
            ObservableAcquisitionDevices.Add(Info3);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<AcquisitionDeviceInfo> ObservableAcquisitionDevices { get => _observableAcquisitionDevices; set => _observableAcquisitionDevices = value; }
    }
```

My xaml code for the combobox looks like this:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cbboxDevices" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableAcquisitionDevices}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Device"/>
```

This is what i get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8WSv.png)

and this is what I'm expecting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK6bv.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: Your explanation does not really make much logical sense, and feels rather incomplete. So, you have a collection of AcquisitionDeviceInfo objects, each with their own string list. Since you have multiple AcquisitionDeviceInfo objects, you will obviously also have multiple string lists. So, which of those multiple string lists  do you want to show in the combobox; or _how_ exactly do you want to display _what_ in the Combobox? **Edit** and improve your question, explaining more **clearly** and **unambiguously** what you actually want to display in the ComboBox **precisely**.

Comment: The way I read the question you have nested data and you want to flatten the contents of each `AquisitionDeviceInfo.Device` list from the whole observable collection. Is that right?
If that is the case, what do you want to do with the selected item of the combo box? Do you want a to reference the `AquisitionDeviceInfo` or do you only care about the string displayed? You could use a template so each item is displayed as a list of strings

Comment: @elgonzo Thank you for your feedback and sorry for not being so clear, english is not my first language. Yeah, i want to display all of the strings from each AcquisitionDeviceInfo object, and my code behind needs to know which string was selected by the user. Ive changed my code and uploaded 2 pictures to show clearly what i'm expecting to happen.

Comment: @strongbutgood Yes that's right. My data is nested and i need to display it. I also need a reference of the selected item in my code behind. I edited my question and uploaded 2 pictures showing what i want. I hope it's easier to understand now. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you create a separate list of items to be shown and selected in the combobox (the type of the items being a class that features properties for the displayed name of the item as well as other data/information your code will need to work with an item selected by a user). Create this items list for the Combobox ItemsSource based on the data from the AcquisitionDeviceInfo objects in the ObservableAcquisitionDevices collection.

Comment: If all you need for the combobox items is just the name of the devices (which then would also mean that the selected item of the combobox would just only be a string with a device name, and nothing more), then composing that items list could be done by just some joe-average Linq query over your ObservableAcquisitionDevices collection...

Comment: @elgonzo Would a linq query over the ObservableCollection provide an Observable enumerable as well? I think you would lose the benefits of data binding because you lose `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` events from the original ObservableCollection when you wrap it in a linq query and the combo box would only show the initial contents of the query when it was first run

Comment: Ahh, no. Sorry, i missed that. The Linq query would _not_ provide an observable collection. If _ObservableAcquisitionDevices_ can change dynamically, you would either need to subscribe to the collection's CollectionChanged event, with an event handler that builds and updates the ComboBox ItemsSource collection according to the received event argument (see @strongbutgood's answer, i guess), or you would have to rethink and restructure your data model so that you actually start with an observable collection that contains items representing individual devices instead of AcquisitionDeviceInfo's...

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your ItemSource

```
 <ComboBox Name="cbboxDevices" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableAcquisitionDevices[0].Device}"
        />
```

Comment: Using an index in XAML is a bad idea.  Not to mention, what about the other # of items in `ObservableAcquisitionDevices`?

Answer (score 0):

To flatten your `ObservableCollection<AcquisitionDeviceInfo>` you will need to observe the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event of that observable collection, then update an `ObservableCollection<string>` with the nested list contents and bind your combo box to the string collection.

```
private ObservableCollection<AcquisitionDeviceInfo> _observableAcquisitionDevices;
private ObservableCollection<string> ObservableDevices { get; private set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableDevices = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    _observableAcquisitionDevices = new ObservableCollection<AcquisitionDeviceInfo>();
    _observableAcquisitionDevices.CollectionChanged += AquisitionDevices_CollectionChanged;

    // set the data context after the property we are binding to is set
    // especially if you don't have property change support in place
    DataContext = this;

    // add data to _observableAcquisitionDevices
}

private void AquisitionDevices_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace) && e.OldItems != null)
    {
        for each (var device in e.OldItems.OfType<AcquisitionDeviceInfo>().Device)
        {
            ObservableDevices.Remove(device);
        }
    }
    if ((e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace) && e.NewItems != null)
    {
        for each (var device in e.NewItems.OfType<AcquisitionDeviceInfo>().Device)
        {
            ObservableDevices.Add(device);
        }
    }
    if (e.Action == Reset)
    {
        ObservableDevices.Clear();
    }
}
```

And the binding to the combo box:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbboxDevices" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableDevices}"
    />
```

Other points to note are if you add any string values to your `AcquisitionDeviceInfo.Device` list after the info item has been added to the observable, these values won't be updated into the UI because the list is not observable and not observed. Also, if you have duplicate device names over multiple info items you'll see some odd behaviour on removing items from the _observableAcquisitionDevices.